# How can I categorize the dimension values in 3 different categories?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I have dimension values from a text file which I need to categorize in 3 different "Distance" sections.

I have to display dimensions on one side and the output distance category on the right side.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
'use strict';

const SIX_FEET = 0.02;
const SIXTEEN_FEET = 0.079;

const dims = [
  ' | Dim:0.05546', ' | Dim:0.05000', ' | Dim:0.05234', ' | Dim:0.06328',
  ' | Dim:0.06718', ' | Dim:0.03828', ' | Dim:0.04218', ' | Dim:0.04921',
  ' | Dim:0.05468', ' | Dim:0.04375', ' | Dim:0.04921', ' | Dim:0.03984',
  ' | Dim:0.05312', ' | Dim:0.05625', ' | Dim:0.05546', ' | Dim:0.06953',
  ' | Dim:0.06250', ' | Dim:0.06250', ' | Dim:0.04453', ' | Dim:0.04921'
].map((dim) => +dim.match(/[\d\.]+/)[0]); // extract the number from string

const categories = {
  '6 feet or less': dims.filter((dim) => dim <= SIX_FEET),
  '6 to 16 feet': dims.filter((dim) => dim > SIX_FEET && dim < SIXTEEN_FEET),
  '16 feet or greater': dims.filter((dim) => dim >= SIXTEEN_FEET),
};

console.log(categories);
```